# Problem with Login password

Tags: login, password, security

when ever I'm logging in, I have set a login password for my account but it is logging in automatically with out asking me for a password. Please tell me what I can do to get rid of this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you unchecked the option when you installed ubuntu . there was option `Ask  password for login`  or some thing other when you create user . 
now you have to run command

```
sudo gpasswd -d username nopasswdlogin
```

or do

```
Settings->User Accounts->Unlock->Automatic Login-> Off
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets try the following:

1. Open `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` with your favorite editor (e. g. `sudo vim /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf`)
2. Comment out the following string:

   ```
   autologin-user=your_login
   ```